# Rest Assured - Json - How to create a Map<time,count> from below JSON response?

Tags: collections, rest-assured

API response json donot have any array name, it only has elements as time and count.
How can I store time and count in a Map.
Below is below Response JSON:

**`[ { "_time": "2021-10-28T00:00:00", "count": 10030.0 }, { "_time": "2021-10-29T00:00:00", "count": 7776.0 } ]`**

I have tried creating two list for _time and count , then storing it in a Map.

```
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res.asString());
        List<Float> count = js.getList("count");
        List<String> time = js.getList("_time");
        Map<String,Float> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Float>();
        Iterator<String> keyIter = time.iterator();
        Iterator<Float> valIter = count.iterator();
        while (keyIter.hasNext() && valIter.hasNext()) {
            map.put(keyIter.next(), valIter.next());
        }
```

But is there any other optimized way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I use this way.

**Step 1:** Deserialize response to POJO

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class TimeObject {
    private String _time;
    private double count;
}
```

```
List<TimeObject> timeObjects = JsonPath.with(res.asString()).getList("", TimeObject.class);
```

**Step2:** Use java stream to collect a Map.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> collect = timeObjects.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(TimeObject::get_time, 
             mapping(TimeObject::getCount, toList())));
System.out.println(collect);
//{2021-10-28T00:00:00=[10030.0], 2021-10-29T00:00:00=[7776.0]}
```